# When does FlexCel's TCellValue.IsDateTime always return false?

Tags: excel, delphi

I am using [TMS' FlexCel Excel document](https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcel.asp) component.  I am - however - having a problem with dates.  As I understand it, Excel has three types: Strings, numbers and datetimes.  This is also represented in FlexCel's `TCellValue`'s methods, such as `IsString`, `IsNumber` and `IsDateTime`.

However, `IsDateTime` *always* returns `False`.  `TCellValue` has a `ToDateTime` function that will *always* return a `TDateTime`.  If the original cell value is not a date, the time will be "1899-12-31T23:59:59".

I am however not keen on the idea using `DateUtils`'s `YearOf()` on `1899` to detect whether it truly was a date.  What if the cell contained a float (`double`)?  That would become a proper `TDateTime`.

I have made sure that the format for these cells are a datetime.  When exporting to Excel's XML Spreadsheet 2003 format, I can see that the cells are properly detected as datetimes by Excel.  Why doesn't FlexCel detect the same thing?

Comment: Adrian Gallero from TMSSoftware explains the reason in http://www.tmssoftware.com/SITE/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=3284&OB=ASC